# Can I make "Discover services in Solution" work for Windows service based WCF services?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, windows-services, hosting

I've got a VS2010 solution with two projects, each containing a Windows service hosting a WCF service. I also have another project as part of the solution that consumes these services.

When I deploy the Windows service based WCF services and then add a service reference via VS everything works fine, but I'd like to add a service reference via `Add Service Reference` => `Discover` => `Services in Solution`. Unfortunately this only seems to work for projects based directly on the WCF service template which I cannot use. I also tried editing the .csproj files for the respective projects as suggested [on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/bbc6d1f6-15f1-40b6-a96d-ab8a9fb52048/), but this also didn't work.

Is there a way to make this work so I don't have to deploy my services to a test server and then add a service reference using its URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is no direct way to accomplish this. What I did was to add projects based on the WCF template and reference these from the Windows Service projects. This way I can use the `Discover` => `Services in Solution` functionality while also hosting the WCF services as a Windows Service.